# Yocto hddimg partition with boot0 blob

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, yocto, u-boot

I'm trying to create a .hddimg in yocto with the following partitions:

- boot0_position=8      # KiB
- uboot_position=19096  # KiB

boot0 is a blob and it loads u_boot. Please can some one help me on
this matter? Where can I configure such parameters?

Comment: What SoC are you using?  There is likely a good example already of how to create a bootable image for that platform.

Comment: Hi @TomRini, I'm using the Pine64 SBC which uses a Allwinner A64 Soc. I think it's kind of new SoC and it has some strange particularities.

Comment: I think I should probably use wic and create a new plugin for boot0 but how can I define the image sector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that we have some details here, OK.  As of this writing [meta-sunxi](https://github.com/linux-sunxi/meta-sunxi/) does not yet support the A64 SoC.  However there is currently https://github.com/linux-sunxi/meta-sunxi/blob/master/classes/sdcard_image-sunxi.bbclass for making images that work on the 32bit SoCs.  It shouldn't be too hard to modify that to put boot0/ATF/U-Boot into the correct locations and I'm sure they would welcome a patch that adds support for the 64bit SoC.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this @TomRini. I'm giving a look at this class and it's very useful.